# Different function outputs for integers and numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having trouble understanding, why I get different values in the following two cases:

-Case 1:

```
def myfunc(a,b,c):
    xx = a+b
    yy = b+c
    return xx, yy

q,w = myfunc(1,2,3)

print(q,w)

Output 1: 3 5
```

-Case 2:

```
import numpy as np

q=w=np.zeros(3)

def myfunc(a,b,c):
    xx = a+b
    yy = b+c
    return xx, yy


for i in range(3):
    q[i],w[i] = myfunc(1,2,3)

print(q,w)

Output 2: [5. 5. 5.] [5. 5. 5.]
```

In the second case, both arrays have their entries equal to 5. Could someone explain, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't talk about the first case because it's simple and clear. For the second case, you have defined the variables q and w as following

> `q=w=np.zeros(3)`

In this case, what ever changes you make in `q` they will be applied to `w` because they q and w have the same address.

When you run this:

> `q[i],w[i] = myfunc(1,2,3)`

`q[i]` gets the value 3 and `w[i]` gets the value 5 and since q and w have the same address, `q[i]` will get the value 5 as well. That explains why you have 5 every time.

If you want to solve it, change the variable definition line from:

```
q=w=np.zeros(3)
```

to :

```
w=np.zeros(3)
q=np.zeros(3)
```

Comment: More precisely, `q` and `w` are both references to the same object created by `np.zeros(3)`. (There is no notion of "address" in Python.)

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I thought I would save space by using q=w=np.zeros(3) instead of w=np.zeros(3)
q=np.zeros(3), but did not know they would be assigned to the same memory address.

Comment: @chepner, yes, that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: @numpy There is no "they"; you only created *one* object, then defined two references two it. Simple assignment *never* creates a copy in Python. Be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.